# What happens to my pre-paid period if I change registrars?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, domain-registrar, domain-transfer

I have a domain at registrar A and it is indicated that I have it payed until 2016. If I transfer it to registrar B today, will I have to pay again for the **from now to 2016** period?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you will not lose any time from your registration.

Most domain transfers add a year to your EXISTING expiry date.

Comment: Whether a year is added to the expiry date (which must be paid for at the time of transfer to the new registrar) is dependent on the TLD (the register that controls that TLD). UK domains, for instance, do not.